# How to make something "instantaneously" in Processing

Tags: processing

So, i'm sorry if this is a weird or stupid question but I genuinely couldn't find an answer. So, the thing is I'm trying to do a visual representation of the multiplication tables, so i divide a circle in a certain number of "slices", for example I divide it in 10. Then I join each point with its product, for example for the 2 times table i make a line between 1 and 2, another one between 2 and 4, 3 and 6 and so on...

The thing is, if i surpass a certain amount of "slices" i can clearly see Processing drawing each one of the lines one by one. I wanted to progressively change the number of slices so you can see how does it evolve, but then the lines would just have to "appear" or change instantaneously since the "animation" makes no sense if you see it drawing every line. Is there a way I can improve the speed of the program, or just make it show all lines at once?

For reference, this is how i kinda want it to look like:

[YouTube video](https://youtu.be/qhbuKbxJsk8?t=737)

**This is the code i'm using (with the ControlP5 library and soooo poorly optimized):**

```
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;
Knob myKnobA;
Knob myKnobB;

int ncosas = 30;
float sumangle = (2*PI)/ncosas;
float angle = HALF_PI + PI + sumangle;
int radius = 100;
int counter = 1;
int sumar = 15;
int tablade = 2;
int prueba = 30;
 
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  background(255);
  textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
  fill(0);
  stroke(0);
  textSize(8);
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  myKnobA = cp5.addKnob("Servo")
               .setRange(1,120)
               .setValue(1)
               .setPosition(20,20)
               .setRadius(30)
               .setDragDirection(Knob.HORIZONTAL)
               .setCaptionLabel("N")
               .setColorCaptionLabel(0)
               ;
           
  myKnobB = cp5.addKnob("TablaD")
               .setRange(1,50)
               .setValue(1)
               .setPosition(20,120)
               .setRadius(30)
               .setDragDirection(Knob.HORIZONTAL)
               .setCaptionLabel("Tabla de")
               .setColorCaptionLabel(0)
               ;
  //translate(height/2,width/2);
  

  //line(0,0,radius*sin(radians(prueba)),radius*cos(radians(prueba)));
  
  
  
}
 
void draw(){
  if(counter <= ncosas){
    dibujar();
  }
}

void Servo(int theValue){
  background(255);
  counter = 1;
  ncosas = theValue;
  sumangle = (2*PI)/ncosas;
  angle = HALF_PI + PI + sumangle;
}

void TablaD(int theValue){
  background(255);
  counter = 1;
  tablade = theValue;
  angle = HALF_PI + PI + sumangle;
}


void dibujar(){
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width*2.5/4,height/2);
  circle(radius*sin(angle),radius*cos(angle),2);
  //if(counter*tablade<=ncosas){
  line(radius*sin(angle),radius*cos(angle),radius*sin((counter*tablade*sumangle)+(angle-counter*sumangle)),radius*cos((counter*tablade*sumangle)+(angle-counter*sumangle)));
  //}
  println(counter*tablade + " -> " + counter*tablade*degrees(sumangle));
  text(counter,(radius+sumar)*sin(angle),(radius+sumar)*cos(angle));
  angle += sumangle;
  counter++;
  popMatrix();
}

void keyPressed(){
  if (key == 'D' || key == 'd'){
      Servo(int(myKnobA.getValue())+1);
      myKnobA.setValue(int(myKnobA.getValue())+1);
  }
  if (key == 'A' || key == 'a'){
      Servo(int(myKnobA.getValue())-1);
      myKnobA.setValue(int(myKnobA.getValue())-1);
  }
  if (key == 'W' || key == 'w'){
      TablaD(int(myKnobB.getValue())+1);
      myKnobB.setValue(int(myKnobB.getValue())+1);
  }
  if (key == 'S' || key == 's'){
      TablaD(int(myKnobB.getValue())-1);
      myKnobB.setValue(int(myKnobB.getValue())-1);
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is one screen updating per call to `draw`. Make sure that several drawing commands are executed in each pass through `draw`. You seem to be using the main processing loop as the only loop in your code, hence are drawing something like 60 distinct things per seconds when you can draw much, much more.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what [John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman) said, you need to execute the `dibujar()` command multiple times in `draw()`. In Processing, the canvas is rendered at the end of the `draw()` loop, so if you draw multiple lines in `draw()`, they will all appear at the same time.

This will involve some kind of loop. If you want to draw the entire multiplication circle at once, you could replace `if` with `while` in the `draw()` loop:

```
void draw(){
  while (counter <= ncosas){
    dibujar();
  }
}
```

I believe this will draw the entire multiplication circle in a single frame. You can then adjust the knobs to change the parameters of the multiplication circle, and the multiplication circle will change as you adjust the knobs.